# date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila') is showing 1 day ahead

Tags: php, date

I have this function `<?php date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila'); echo date("F j, Y"); ?>` but it is showing one day ahead of time. I checked my pc time but it is correct. Today is November 20, 2016 but it shows November 21, 2016. What is the problem with this?

Comment: What time did you check? Print echo date("F j, Y H:i:s");  and check how many hours ahead is printing

Comment: Is it running locally or on an external server?

Comment: The current time here is 8:59 and it shows 12:58:29. And it is running locally